# AWS CloudWatch - Creating a metric from different datapoints in time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to define CW metric as the difference between the same metrics, but in two consecutive data points in time?

I need to measure how many objects has been put in an S3 bucket for a given time period, so I would use make the difference NumberOfObjects in this time window. PS: I couldn't find any "New objects" metric (which is not the same of PutRequests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'DIFF' function.

It returns the difference between each value in the time series and the preceding value from that time series.

Expression:

```
DIFF(m1)
```

I do not have much data to test it but in this example I had added 2 new objects and using that expression shows the new objects added that day.

[image]

---

Reference:

[Functions supported for metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html)